# Rails vendor folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, zurb-foundation

I'm using the [zurb-foundation](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-rails) gem, but it uses foundation 2 while foundation 3 came out today. Looking at the gem repository, there is a folder called vendor/assets which holds all of the assets (javascripts/css/images). If I download the new foundation assets and put them in the vendor/assets folder in my Rails app, will it override the gem assets?

Comment: Yes, that will work. But then you will have to maintain that. But why don't you go ahead and update the gem and then make a pull request? They will appreciate it for sure.

Comment: @Nerian Thanks for the info, if you could put that as an answer, I'll be able to accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any asset that you add to your assets folder will take precedence over any asset that is added from a gem – which will use the vendor folder.

So in your case, add your files to the assets folder – not the vendor one.

Notice that you will need to maintain that code, so while in the short term this will work, in the long term you may want to update the zurb-foundation gem yourself and then make a pull request.